# Blacklisting your own faulty hackage release

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I've accidentally uploaded a faulty distribution and tried to reupload it right away, but `cabal` replied with:

```
This version of the package has already been uploaded.

As a matter of policy we do not allow package tarballs to be changed after a
release (so we can guarantee stable md5sums etc). The usual recommendation is
to upload a new version, and if necessary blacklist the existing one. In
extraordinary circumstances, contact the administrators.
```

Okay, I've incremented the version and uploaded the correct distro, but now I am interested in blacklisting the faulty release, as suggested. However there is no notion about how to do that anywhere whatsoever. How to do that? And what do they actually imply by the term "blacklisting"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to your package page on `Hackage`. Scroll down to `Maintainers' corner` and click on `edit package information`. Then you'll have an option to click on `Preferred versions`.

This page allows you to specify `version ranges` or `deprecate individual package versions`.

Deprecated versions won't be completely gone, but `cabal-install` will try to respect the preferences when trying to resolve dependencies.

Comment: If "soft" deprecation is not enough, there's also the workaround to edit the `.cabal` file on Hackage to insert an unsatisfiable condition (like `build-depends: base<0`) to force the cabal solver to reject such a package version. But this should only be used as a last resort if that package version is broken beyond repair.