# Triggering a documentation update for a Hackage package

Tags: haskell, hackage

I have two releases which were accidentally uploaded before some of their dependencies:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-cereal-plus-0.3.1
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-structure-0.1.0

Since then their dependencies have long been satisfied, however the documentation for them has not been generated to this day.

**How can I trigger a reevaluation of those releases by Hackage?** Is uploading a new release the only solution to such a silly problem?

I could find nothing related in the "Maintainer's corner".

Comment: You could try uploading it with the same version again. Not sure if it works, just a guess.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Nope. That won't work due to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21724729/485115).

Answer (score 2):

From [New features in Hackage 2](http://hackage.haskell.org/new-features).

> Documentation can be uploaded by any suitably-authorised user, not just a single dedicated documentation build bot. In particular maintainers can upload documentation bundles if the doc build bots fail to do so.

There's a [Github Issue](https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/issues/56) complaining that the documentation for this is incomplete, and linked from this thread is a [shell script](https://gist.github.com/stbuehler/7068764) that automatically builds, bundles, and uploads documentation for you. Give it a try, and post results.